# How to align text boxes in yii2 form field?

Tags: javascript, css, yii2

I have a checkbox in my form field , its a multiple checkbox with single array of values its appears one below one and i need it to appear side by side.

I used css properties to change but it does not works.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'ReportSelection[]')->checkboxList(['1' => 'Channel1', '2' => 'Channel2','3'=>'Channel3','4'=>'Channel4','5' => 'Channel5', '6' => 'Channel6','7'=>'Channel7','8'=>'Channel8','9' => 'Channel9','10' => 'Channel10', '11' => 'Channel11','12'=>'Channel12','13'=>'Channel13','14' => 'Channel14', '15' => 'Channel15','16'=>'Channel16','17'=>'Channel17','18' => 'Channel18','19'=>'Channel19','20'=>'Channel20','21'=>'Channel21','22' => 'Channel22', '23' => 'Channel23','24'=>'Channel24','25'=>'Channel25','26' => 'Channel26', '27' => 'Channel27','28'=>'Channel28','29'=>'Channel29','30' => 'Channel30', '31' => 'Channel31','32'=>'Channel32'],['multiple'=>'multiple']); ?>
```

I expect the output to be like checkboxes side by side,but it is one below one.

Comment: try use 'class' => 'your-class-name' and style it in css

Comment: How to alter these checkbox one by one?

Comment: you need it to appear side by side 

 in css style use .class-name { display:inline-block; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `->inline(true)`

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'ReportSelection[]')
     ->inline(true)
     ->checkboxList(['1' => 'Channel1'
                  ,'2' => 'Channel2'
                  ,'3' => 'Channel3'
                  ,'4' => 'Channel4'
                  ,'5' => 'Channel5'
                  .....
                  .....
                  ,'30' => 'Channel30'
                  ,'31' => 'Channel31'
                  ,'32' => 'Channel32'],['multiple'=>'multiple']); ?>
```

Comment: how to make checkbox disable on certain contions from db

Comment: @sabarilogesh  your comment is not clear to me  ..  you should post a new proper question .. eventually comment me the link  ..